# cURL error 60: SSL certificate p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m: certificate is not yet valid (LEMP WordPress + PHP7)

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have moved to PHP7 today as well as Nginx 1.10. I am having an issue on on my WordPress backend.

> WordPress function wp_remote_get() test failed. Looks like your server is not fully compatible with WordPress. Contact your hosting provider. Error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid

I have been reading resolutions for this for quite a while now. I have downloaded the CA bundle from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem modified the php.ini.

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

Do I need to append the bundle to an existing bundle? Do I need to modify permissions on the cacert.pem?

The issue is occurring on the import sample data page.  I am using Lets Encrypt SSL.

Comment: Is your server's date/time correct?

Comment: THANK YOU ceejayoz! Thank you so very much, I am grateful.

Comment: Glad that helped. Turn on NTP so it doesn't recur. :-)

Comment: ceejayoz you saved me !